# HOW are harmonics generated in longitudinal waves on the particle level?

Tags: waves, acoustics, resonance, non-linear-systems, harmonics

I have been looking through the physics.se and all over the internet for weeks now honestly, and I still don't understand how harmonics are formatted on the particle level. Yes, I know that only certain wavelengths fit an integer number of times into the length of the system and I understand how and why they would resonate if we drive the system with the frequency matching this wavelength. I see how the incident and reflected waves would have constructive interference and create nodes and antinodes.

However what I fail to understand is how a single pulse or a driving force at the fundamental frequency can possibly lead to formation of harmonics? The compressions at the fundamental frequency travel from one end to the other and back, only to be met with newly introduced disturbance wave. At what point and how do the particles of the wavefront separate into distinct wavefront of the harmonics?

EDIT: Are the harmonic frequencies introduced by the forcing vibration in the first place? For example by non-linearities in vibrations of lip-buzzing, reeds, mouthpieces and oral cavities - or are there other phenomena that are causing harmonics? Would a sine wave driving a trumpet at its natural frequency (lip buzzing at only one resonant frequency of the trumpet) create harmonics, and if yes how?

And again just to be clear, I am NOT asking how and why they resonate once they are created and what frequencies fit the Fourier series etc - but the principle of their creation in the first place.

Comment: I believe that you what you are asking is related to non-linear acoustics. In linear acoustics, there is no generation of frequencies that were **not** present in the input (or the forcing function) of a system. Thus, for example in pipes and/or musical instruments, the forcing function is wideband and only the "resonant frequencies" (apologies for abuse of the term but I believe it communicates the meaning) "surive".

Comment: So if we take for example a trumpet - all of the (or most of) the harmonics are the consequence of instability/non-linearities in the buzzing of the lips? I mean that would explain it, but is that really the case?

Comment: Most probably not. To my (rather limited indeed) knowledge, the resulting spectrum of the trumpet (just using the same example) is the filtered (from the tube) response of the wideband excitation resulting from the lips (buzzing or whatever is that they do). So, consider a wideband (white- or pink-noise like) excitation which is filtered by the tube which is the body of the trumpet and only the supported frequencies (kinda the resonances) are what comes out, since the rest of the frequencies are not supported by the tube.

Comment: But how does this wideband, pink-noise like disturbance get generated in the first place? The buzzing of the lips definitely has a pitch, it definitely is not white noise like.
( see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2q6tA_SkYTE for reference)
It is not a bad idea that I record and check the spectrum of the buzzing. It might indeed be broadband enough to create the basis for resonance harmonic overtones. However I still don't understand how is it that you think this white-noise-like disturbance is generated?

Comment: To further complicate the situation, there also might be some effect of the coupling of the larynx, vocal tract and lips and the waves in the trumpet, which might result in resonance at the upper harmonic frequencies - which might not be available to hear when listening to the buzzing on it's own.
( http://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/brassacoustics.html#sound )

Comment: And then again it might be the effect of the bell, the particles might indeed be reflecting at shorter wavelengths coming back towards the player and hitting the slanted wall of the bell as it flares outwards. It's hard to say as all the instruments that "buzzing" flare out. Flute has very few overtones but the sound is introduced very differently, and it is open-open at both end, so there's that as well, making it a bit hard to figure out.

Comment: "If we play softly, and especially if we play a high note softly, the lips don't move fast enough and don't have enough time to close completely. In this case we observe approximately sinusoidal vibrations: the system is behaving like the linear mass-and-spring oscillator of physics texts. This means that the fundamental in the sound spectrum is strong, but that the higher harmonics are weak. This gives rise to a mellow timbre. Playing loudly, the lips do close, and may close abruptly. This gives what physicists call clipping and strongly nonlinear behavior, which produce more high harmonics."

Comment: I am not sure why you think that there would be a particle level explanation here. Particle sized musical instruments don’t exist for good reasons. The harmonics are based on the size and shape of the instrument. You cannot neglect that and just look at particles

Comment: Why not? The generation and reflection of the fundamental frequency can be very well explained on the level of particles. Even the harmonics, once present can be explained on this scale - how the wavefront progresses, how it collides elastically and transfers energy, how the compressions superimpose and rarefactions get filled and so on. It's not so much "neglecting" the shape of the instrument as it is explaining it's influence on the particles. It without a doubt happens, so what's stopping us to explain it, on a conceptual level at least?

Comment: That being said, I don't have an explanation on any scale, from any angle of why and how harmonics are generated in air columns - unless the forcing vibration is of that frequency. Like ZaellixA said, it might be that the driving force is introducing many different frequencies, but I am not sure if that is the (only) reason how they emerge. How resonant frequencies are supported by shape and damping I can understand, to a satisfactory degree at least. What I'm curious is whether a sine wave driving a trumpet at its natural frequency creates harmonics?

Comment: @Dimitri, although I am not an expert in the topic, I really doubt you could find an excitation signal (such as "lips buzzing") that is purely monochromatic. In this regard, if the signal is not "pink-noise-like" (I may have used a bad term and this caused confusion), it does have many frequencies, and from those, only the ones that are supported by the instrument "survive" (make it to the steady state). You could experiment in two ways. 1) Excite the instrument with a mono-frequency component and observe the output and 2) excite the instrument with a "pink-like" signal and again observe.

Comment: No, no, you got the point across with the white-noise-like. And further I think you are on point with that. Reading more about brass, trumpet specifically it seems that a mere fraction of energy ends up in the body of the trumpet, not negligible but I think to little to account for noticeably strong harmonics. I was trying to find some experiments but it seems I'll have to do some experimenting myself. I'll post if I have any updates either way. I'm still trying to figure out exactly what are effects of the bell, turns out it's much more complicated than I thought it would be, as per usual. :D